# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - .net Web API and JS AJAX

Tags: c#, html, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to use Ajax to capture a submit event and then send the form elements formatted as JSON to a asp.net Web API 2. I am using the latest version of FireFox. Ad blocker is disabled. I have an SSL on both origin and destination. I have followed the steps in this guide to Enable cross-origin requests.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I have tested that my form with out javascript can send to the API no problem and recieve results.
I have also tested using Postman.

I would like to capture the response from the API and show it in an alert message.

here is a screen shot of the error in the browser
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3mhL.jpg

here is a screen shot from postman of the server response confirming it accepts all
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRRjw.jpg

Here is my HTML
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TLogin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css">
    <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var form = $('#login_form')[0];
            form.onsubmit = function (e) {
                var data = $("#login_form :input").serializeArray();
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "https://api.website.org/api/users/login",
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: false
                    },
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                    
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhrRequest, status, error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(xhrRequest));
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="login_form">
        <div class="master_container">
            <div id="views_container" class="clear">
                <div class="view_container">
                    <span>Username :</span>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="view_container">
                    <span>Password :</span>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                </div>                
                <div class="view_container">
                    <input id="ip" type="hidden" value="myip" />
                    <input type="submit" id="Button_Login" value="Login" />
                </div>
                <div class="view_container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Here is my API Controller Info
`

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "*", SupportsCredentials = false)]   
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {       

        //user login
        [Route("api/Users/Login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public UsersSession Login(Users users)
        {
            UsersSession UsersSession = new UsersSession();
            UsersSession.result = new Result();
            try
            {
                if (users != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(users.username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(users.password))
                {
                    var v_meta_list = new List<string>();
                    var v_search_results = new List<string>();
                    
                    v_meta_list.Add("username=" + users.username);
                    v_meta_list.Add("password=" + users.password);
                    v_search_results = CL_db.db_search("4", v_meta_list, true);


                    if (v_search_results != null && v_search_results.Count > 0)
                    {
                        UsersSession.userid = v_search_results[0];

                        UsersSession.result.result = true;
                        UsersSession.result.message = "success";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UsersSession.result.result = false;
                        UsersSession.result.message = "Invalid user";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    UsersSession.result.result = false;
                    UsersSession.result.message = "Please enter username and password";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UsersSession.result.result = false;
                UsersSession.result.message = "Error occurred: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return UsersSession;
        } 
   }
```

`Here is the web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

`

Comment: Your preflight (`OPTIONS`) request fails with a 500 error -- don't know why, as you don't show anything about your CORS configuration --  so the browser won't execute the actual request at all. Postman doesn't care about CORS, so it doesn't send an `OPTIONS` request ...

Comment: Where do I find my CORS configuration information?

Comment: Ah, I have missed the very first line: `origins: "the-manager.org"` is invalid, you have to add a protocol (like `https://the-manager.org`)

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
</system.webServer>

Comment: I changed it to "*" for all. getting this error now
https://imgur.com/a/3wM7M1Y

Comment: Well, now your backend seems to set `*, *` as allowed headers which doesn't make any sense ...

Comment: I updated the description of the post please review the code and let me know what you think is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I had the cors stuff defined in too many locations.
The solution was simply to only have the code for the WebApiConfig.cs
I removed the code from the web.config and the controller.